# Android Studio ERROR: Cause: executing external native build for cmake /path/to/project/app/tools/CMakeLists.txt

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have downloaded WireGuard from Github ([link](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android)) after run app by android studio I have this error:

```
ERROR: Cause: executing external native build for cmake  /path/to/project/app/tools/CMakeLists.txt
```

and `android_gradle_generate_cmake_ninja_json_x86.stderr.txt` show this:

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable):
    Cannot find source file:

    wireguard-tools/src/wg-quick/android.c

    Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
    .hxx .in .txx


    CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: libwg-quick.so
```

wireguard-tools folder is empty. maybe it's content must build by cmake from CMakeLists.txt.
I don't understand cmake.
CMakeLists.txt content is:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
# Copyright © 2018-2019 WireGuard LLC. All Rights Reserved.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")

# Work around https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/602
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=gold")

add_executable(libwg-quick.so wireguard-tools/src/wg-quick/android.c ndk-compat/compat.c)
target_compile_options(libwg-quick.so PUBLIC -O3 -std=gnu11 -Wall -include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ndk-compat/compat.h -DWG_PACKAGE_NAME=\"${ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME}\")
target_link_libraries(libwg-quick.so -ldl)

file(GLOB WG_SOURCES wireguard-tools/src/*.c libmnl/src/*.c ndk-compat/compat.c)
add_executable(libwg.so ${WG_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(libwg.so PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wireguard-tools/src/uapi/" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wireguard-tools/src/")
target_compile_options(libwg.so PUBLIC -O3 -std=gnu11 -D_GNU_SOURCE -idirafter "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libmnl/include/" -include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ndk-compat/compat.h -DHAVE_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN -DRUNSTATEDIR=\"/data/data/${ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME}/cache\" -Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter)

add_custom_target(libwg-go.so WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libwg-go" COMMENT "Building wireguard-go" VERBATIM COMMAND make
    ANDROID_ARCH_NAME=${ANDROID_ARCH_NAME}
    ANDROID_C_COMPILER=${ANDROID_C_COMPILER}
    ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT=${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}
    ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE=${ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE}
    ANDROID_SYSROOT=${ANDROID_SYSROOT}
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME=${ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME}
    CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}\ -Wno-unused-command-line-argument
    LDFLAGS=${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}\ -fuse-ld=gold
    DESTDIR=${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    BUILDDIR=${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/../generated-src
)
# Hack to make it actually build as part of the default target
add_dependencies(libwg.so libwg-go.so)
```

project structure:

[image]

i'm using Android studio 3.5.3 and gradle 5.4.1 in ubuntu 18.04.
NDK(side by side) , LLDB and CMake also installed. however I see this warning(not error) in event log : `NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN` in all projects. even those that not using ndk.
in local.properties I defined :

```
ndk.dir=/home/hadi/Dev/Android/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669
sdk.dir=/home/hadi/Dev/Android/android-sdk
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this repository have some sub modules and must clone with extra options.
as in readme file in github page mentioned, I must clone project by these commands:

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-android
$ cd wireguard-android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Do you know how to use this source code to establish a vpn connection?

Comment: @Md.IkramulMurad, this source code is a complete app and you can modify it. you must have a server and establish Wireguard on it then make a client and use it in Android App.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a complete app. But unfortunately, nothing found a clear concept to establish a connection. Like any specific API to start a wire-guard connection.

I've seen that they use setState API of GoBackend class in which they pass tunnel, config, and state.
But when I use this API, I get UNABLE_TO_START_VPN error.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's unclear how to start the tunnel to connect to a remote Wireguard server. I wished there was at least a simple example in the readme.